# What does the Torah say about one's face?

Tags: sources-mekorot, soul, face

a) What does the Torah say about one's ***face***?

b) What the does one's face *represent*?

c) Does one's face have a connection to his *soul*?

Comment: Hello.  Your edit is a pretty major change that invalidates an answer that was already present.  I'm rolling it back for that reason.  Please feel free to ask your newer version as a *new* question.  (You can get the text from the edit history by clicking on the "edited" link.)

Comment: @MonicaCellio is acting according to our [policy regarding changing questions after a period of time](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1229/5151), btw.

Comment: Isn't part (a) way too broad? The Torah mentions faces all over the place. cc @MonicaCellio

Comment: @msh210 that could be; I'm not sure if "one's face" is a smaller subset of all the mentions of "faces".  (The question would be better with more context or background.)  I was only restoring the question to its prior state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Gemara (Brachos 58a) writes that just as the appearance of one's face is unique, so is one's personality. R. Tzadok of Lublin (Dover Tzedek) explains this comparison on the principle that

> עיקר הנפש היא בפנים

Rough translation: The soul is mostly in the face.

R. Ezekiel Landau explains the Gemara similarly (Tzlach to Berachos ch. 9 58b I think)

This explanation is probably rooted in the kabbalistic belief of חכמת הפרצוף equivalent as far as I can tell to [Physiognomy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physiognomy). See also reference to it [here](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%AA_%D7%94%D7%A4%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%9D#.D7.91.D7.A7.D7.91.D7.9C.D7.94). For an example of this belief in rabbinic literature see R. Bachye's commentary to Yisro (ch. 18).